# Convergence of $L^2$ functions with conditions on their Fourier transforms

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Let $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a Cauchy sequence of $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ functions, where $\mathbb{T}=[-\pi,\pi)$. Assume that, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ and for $k\geq 0$, the following inequality holds:

$$\sum_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty} (1+m^2)^k |\hat{f_n}(m)|^2 \lt +\infty$$

where $\hat{f_n}$ is the Fourier transform of $f_n$.

I have to show that this sequence converges to a function $f\in L^2(\mathbb{T})$ which satisfies the same inequality.

This question is related to another problem I posted here a few days ago (the link is below), but I couldn't find a solution.

As another user said, probably the best way to approach this problem is to notice that, if $||\cdot||_2$ is the usual norm in $L^2(\mathbb{T})$, the sequence converges to a function $f$ in $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ and then to show that

$$\sum_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty} (1+m^2)^k |\hat{f_n}(m)-\hat{f}(m)|^2 \rightarrow 0$$

as $n \rightarrow+\infty$, but I really don't know how to show it. Any ideas?

Previous question: [Real positive index Sobolev spaces are Hilbert spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3065351/real-positive-index-sobolev-spaces-are-hilbert-spaces/3065385#3065385)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is not true for $k\ge 1$. ($k=0$ case is trivial by Parseval's identity.) Note that any trigonometric polynomial $f$ satisfies the condition
$$
\sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}} (1+|j|^2)^k |\widehat{f}(j)|^2 <\infty.\tag{*}
$$ 
Let $F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin nx}{n}=\frac{\pi-x}{2}$, $0<x<2\pi$ and $f_n$ be the Fourier series of $F$. Then each $f_n$ converges to $F$ in $L^2$-norm and satisfies $(*)$. However, since $|\widehat{F}(j)| \ge \frac{c}{|j|}, j\ne 0$ for some $c>0$, $(*)$ cannot hold for $F$ for all $k\ge 1$. This can be a counterexample : $f_n$ is Cauchy in $L^2$ and satisfies $(*)$ but the limit $F$ does not.

**EDIT**: Define a norm as$$
\|f\|_s^2 = \sum_{j\in\Bbb Z}(1+|j|^2)^{s}|\widehat{f}(j)|^2.
$$ Suppose $f_n$ is Cauchy in $\|\cdot\|_s$, i.e.
$$
\sum_{j\in\Bbb Z}(1+|j|^2)^{s}|\widehat{f_n}(j)-\widehat{f_m}(j)|^2\to 0
$$ as $n,m\to\infty$. Then for each fixed $j$, $\widehat{f_n}(j)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb C$ and $\lim_n \widehat{f_n}(j) =: s_j$ exists. Since $\|f_n-f_m\|^2_{L^2(\Bbb T)}\le \|f_n-f_m\|^2_s$, there exists $f\in L^2(\Bbb T)$ such that $f_n\to f$ in $L^2(\Bbb T)$ and $\widehat{f}(j) = s_j$. Now, for a given $\epsilon>0$, we can find $N\in\Bbb N$ such that
$$
\sum_{j\in\Bbb Z}(1+|j|^2)^{s}|\widehat{f_n}(j)-\widehat{f_m}(j)|^2\le \epsilon^2
$$ for all $n,m\ge N$. Observe that for all finite $J\in\Bbb N$,
$$
\sum_{j=-J}^J(1+|j|^2)^{s}|\widehat{f_n}(j)-\widehat{f_m}(j)|^2\le \epsilon^2
$$ for all $n,m\ge N$. Take $m\to\infty$. Then
$$
\sum_{j=-J}^J(1+|j|^2)^{s}|\widehat{f_n}(j)-\widehat{f}(j)|^2\le \epsilon^2.
$$ Take $J\to\infty$. Then
$$
\sum_{j\in\Bbb Z}(1+|j|^2)^{s}|\widehat{f_n}(j)-\widehat{f}(j)|^2\le \epsilon^2
$$ for all $n\ge N$. This proves $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n -f\|_s^2 =0$$ and $$
\|f\|_s^2<\infty
$$as desired.

Comment: Ok, you're right! And what if $\sum_{j=-\infty}^{+\infty}(1+j^2)^s|\hat{f_n}(j)-\hat{f}(j)|^2 \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow 0$? @Song

Comment: @Lukath We can fix the statement: if $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy in the sense that $$\sum_j (1+|j|^2)^s \|\widehat{f}_n(j)-\widehat{f}_m(j)|^2 \to 0$$ as $n,m\to \infty$, then the limit $f=\lim_n f_n$ satisfies $(*)$. So the answer is affirmative.

Comment: How could I show this one? I tried, but I don't know how to show that $|\hat{f_n}(j)-\hat{f}(j)|^2$, for $n$ sufficiently large, is arbitrarely small. @Song

Comment: @Lukath I added the part explaining it in more details.